# How to send formdata with other data in MERN App?

Tags: html, reactjs, multipartform-data, mern

I want to save a image to cloudiary from Nodejs in a Mern Application. I have data in such a way that formdata is a field.

I want to send multiple fields from frontend with formdata but whenever I am trying to assign the formdata to my object, it is getting assigned as empty object {}

Code for Component where I have 2 more fields apart from formdata or file input.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function About({ setAboutInfo, touched = false, setInvalid }) {
  const [about, setAbout] = useState({
    name: "",
    objective: "",
    imageUrl: {},
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    if (e.target.name == "imageUrl") {
      formData.append("imageUrl", e.target.files[0]);
      setAbout({ ...about, imageUrl: formData });
    } else setAbout({ ...about, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    setAboutInfo(about);

    if (!(about.name && about.objective)) {
      setInvalid((prev) => ({ ...prev, about: true }));
    } else {
      setInvalid((prev) => ({ ...prev, about: false }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="ext-container row pb-0">
      <form encType="multipart/form-data">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label className="my-labels" htmlFor="">
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            value={about.name}
            name="name"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            className={"my-inputs "}
            placeholder="Enter complete name"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label className="my-labels" htmlFor="">
            Profile Pic
          </label>

>           <input
>             name="imageUrl"
>             type="file"
>             accept="image/*"
>             onChange={handleChange}
>             className={"my-inputs "}
>             placeholder="Choose profile pic"
>           />

        </div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <label className="my-labels" htmlFor="">
            Objective
          </label>
          <textarea
            name="objective"
            value={about.objective}
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            className={"my-inputs "}
            rows={4}
            placeholder="Enter Objective"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

I am sending this data to parent component from setAboutInfo method.

Parent component making request to backend

```
  const saveData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTouched(true);

    console.log({
      ...about,
    }); 

// console output
**
    {
     name: 'Jack', objective: "Jack's objective", imageUrl: FormData}
     imageUrl: FormData {}
     name: "Jack"
     objective: "Jack's objective"
     [[Prototype]]: Object
    }

**
    axios
      .post(
        "/resume",{...about})
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 201) {
          console.log(response);
          success("Data saved successfully");
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
```

In backend I am getting this as  body of Post request

```
{ name: 'Jack', objective: "Jack's objective", imageUrl: {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append whole body in formdata and send send form data to the api.

```
const saveData = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   setTouched(true);

   console.log({
     ...about,
   }); 

// console output
**
   {
    name: 'Jack', objective: "Jack's objective", imageUrl: FormData}
    imageUrl: FormData {}
    name: "Jack"
    objective: "Jack's objective"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
   }

**

let formData = new FormData();
   
     formData.append("imageUrl", about.imageUrl);
     formData.append("name", about.name);
     formData.append("objective", about.objective);


   axios
     .post(
       "/resume",formData )
     .then((response) => {
       if (response.status == 201) {
         console.log(response);
         success("Data saved successfully");
       }
     })
     .catch((e) => console.log(e));
 };
```

For onchange method don't save in form data.

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name == "imageUrl") {
      setAbout({ ...about, imageUrl: e.target.files[0]});
    } else setAbout({ ...about, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    setAboutInfo(about);

    if (!(about.name && about.objective)) {
      setInvalid((prev) => ({ ...prev, about: true }));
    } else {
      setInvalid((prev) => ({ ...prev, about: false }));
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is there any other way to send the data? Actually this about is a child component and I am sending the request through its parent component. I have more 5 components just like About component.